# Android Eclipse set logcat to receive input from emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation, logcat

What I think happened is that logcat is listening for a different emulator that I already closed. How/can I tell logcat the number of the emulator that it is supposed to be displaying errors for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the correct device you want to listen on the `Device` view (I uppose you're using eclipse).
If you don't have a `Device` view, open it from `Window` -> `Show View` -> `Device`

Answer (score 1):

Click the DDMS tab and in the device tab there should be a "down
arrow button" next to the screenshot button. Press that and all the
way at the bottom should be reset ADB.
Hope this helps.